# Are "map" and "filter" subclasses of the class "iterator"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read in the python documentation that `map` and `filter` return "iterator" object.
but when I check the type of the returned object, I find that it's of type `<class 'filter'>` and `<class 'map'>`

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
print(type(filter(lambda i: i>2, x)))
    <class 'filter'>
print(iter(x))
    <class 'list_iterator'>
```

what is the relation of the class `map` with the class `iterator`? Does `map`, `filter` or `zip` class inherit from the `iterator` class?
I also saw that there are multiple types of iterators depending on the source variable.
for example:

```
x = (1,2,3,4)
print(type(iter(x)))
     <class 'tuple_iterator'>
x = [1,2,3,4]
print(type(iter(x)))
     <class 'list_iterator'>
x = "1234"
print(type(iter(x)))
     <class 'str_iterator'>
```

Are `tuple_iterator`, `list_iterator` and `str_iterator` classes that inherit from an abstract class `iterator` that we don't know about?
Finally, where can I see the actual implementation of the class `map` and `list_iterator`?

Comment: In Python many of these kind of things are "protocols", which is similar to what Java and C# call an "interface", except implicitly defined. So there is not a subtyping relation, only types that satisfy the protocol. Later when type annotations were added to Python it became possible to explicitly define your own protocols https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/ for type-checking purposes.

Comment: iterator is **not a type** it is a *protocol* (or "interface")

Comment: Why don't you use the `issubclass` function to find out?

Comment: @Alexander they are actually classes, but that is an implementation detail. But you can verify this for yourself: `isinstance(map, type)` and `isinstance(filter, type)` will both be `True`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I originally made the same distinction, but deleted it. [They're certainly types](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bdfb6943861431a79e63f0da2e6b3fe163c12bc7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L623), but Python seems to consider a "class" to be a type that's user-defined.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no, that is *absolutely not true*. All types are classes. Those are essentially synonyms (leaving aside "type hints").  The distinction between user-defined classes, types, etc was removed when this was all unified in the Python 2-3. But the process started earlier in the language evolution: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/

Comment: @Alexander ok, but some of those are *actually types/classes by the standard*, e.g. `int`, `list`, etc. That is why the docs have `class int` there (you'll note that `map` and `filter` don't).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was relying on the glossary, which is apparently out-of-date. I never wrote Python 2, so I'm not familiar with the old way classes worked.

Comment: @Carcigenicate understandable, but it's just a big deal in the history of the language. Thankfully, it is totally behind us!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Valid point, but neither does `abs` `min` `all` and many of the others that actually are built-in-functions.  I will remove my comment since it no longer adds any value anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iterator` is the "interface". It describes the capabilities of the object, not the concrete type of the object. I have [this difficult-to-search-for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) page bookmarked for reference.

If you find the [`Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator) entry (or, as suggested, the one [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)), you'll see that an iterator is an object that is capable of producing an iterator (itself) using `__iter__`, and is capable of producing elements using `__next__`. Many such objects exist, from generators returned by generator expressions and generator functions, to the objects returned by `map` and `filter`. That page is for ABCs, which suggests subclassing, but subclassing is not required. Python makes heavy use of "duck typing" which relies on objects having the correct capabilities, but not necessarily a certain type. Any object with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods will work as an iterator.

Comment: So, `collections.abc.Iterator` isn't really relevant, the more relevant link is really here, where the protocol is defined: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just like that page. It may be specifically for ABCs, but it nicely summarizes what methods are expected for different "interfaces". I added the more relevant one though as well.